# Unsubmit a form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I need a form to be able to be both `$dirty` and not `$submitted` for my validation to work.

I'm trying to accomplish this through CSS using the `.ng-invalid`, `.ng-dirty`, and `.ng-submitted` classes that get dynamically added by angular. This means I cannot simply set `$submitted` to false on the form as this will not remove the associated class. Nor can I use `$setPristine` or `$setUntouched` as these will remove the `$dirty` flag and its class.

Is there some way to set a form as unsubmitted so that the `.ng-submitted` class is removed AND the form remains dirty?

Comment: You can use `$setPristine` followed by  `$setDirty`

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nCgu7eBWAXwO3xeYTa6V?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$setPristine` followed by `$setDirty`. If you want to retain the `$dirty` value, save it before setting it to pristine.

```
var formWasDirty = form.$dirty;

form.$setPristine(); 

if (formWasDirty) { 
  form.$setDirty();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nCgu7eBWAXwO3xeYTa6V?p=preview

Comment: Keep in mind this discards the dirty status on the individual form controls.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [there isn't a built in](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) `$setUnsubmitted` function in Angular.

However, the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L279) for the `$setSubmitted` function is very simple. You can easily leverage a decorator on the form directive to provide this functionality.

```
angular.module('YourModule').directive('form', function() {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
            form.$setUnsubmitted = function() {
                element.removeClass('ng-submitted');
                form.$submitted = false;
                if (form.$$parentForm.$setUnsubmitted) { // may be nullFormCtrl
                    form.$$parentForm.$setUnsubmitted();
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Should the Angular team choose the include this method in the future, you would simply remove this decorator with no changes to other code.

[Plunk example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMoLyyFOX78aD3FhoC0W?p=preview)

Comment: Nice, the only thing I'm torn about is that it mimics native angular behaviour in naming. IF a version of angular would be updated where `$setUnsubmitted` exists (which is not unlikely), this would override it to much possible confusion. I'd consider renaming it, you could even add a clause that logs a message that the method now exists and the script should be removed. Something like http://plnkr.co/edit/zg4isVLStZ2S2Edbg7c7?p=preview

Comment: The naming was intentional to avoid any major refactoring if the Angular team were to introduce this method. Simply remove this custom decorator and no other changes throughout your code would be necessary. I'd expect any developer to review changes to a library before upgrading, but if you are worried about forgetting you could always keep the name _and_ include the logging as the decorator runs after the built-in directive.