# Angular JS Form reset with Pristine not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have login form,
i cleared the form after form submitssion,and set form as Pristine mode.
but error message is still remain.

Here is my code,

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && login(user)" novalidate style="position: relative">
    <div class="log-input-frm mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label textfield-demo">
        <div class="col-sm-12 f_name">
            <input ng-model="user.username" name="username" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required="">
            <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted || loginForm.username.$touched" ng-model="loginForm.username">
                <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required" class="text-danger">Please enter email address.</span>
                <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.email" class="text-danger">Please enter valid email address.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="log-input-frm mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label textfield-demo">
        <div class="col-sm-12 f_name">
            <input ng-model="user.password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
            <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted || loginForm.password.$touched" ng-model="loginForm.password">
                <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required" class="text-danger">Please enter password.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <span class="signup pull-left">
            <a ui-sref="forgotpassword">Forgot password</a>
        </span>
        <div class="link">
            <div class="link" style="padding-bottom:0;">
                <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised primary" > Login </md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller code to reset form and set in pristine mode.

```
$scope.loginForm.$setPristine();
$scope.loginForm.$setUntouched();
$scope.user = {};
```

Where am i wrong???

Comment: Perhaps you need to make form unsubmitted. here is a useful link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233876/unsubmit-a-form-in-angular

Comment: i tried as per above link is given but note working, it's show `Error: $scope.loginForm.$setPristine is not a function`

Comment: It should work.. you could provide a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/) to illustrate your situation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using timeout function

```
$scope.user = {};
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.loginForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.loginForm.$setUntouched();
    $scope.loginForm.$submitted = false;
});
```