# Submitted form state preventing

Tags: css, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, form-submit

How can I avoid submitted state (and `ng-submitted` class & submitted scope property as true boolean) in a form when it is submitted?

**Updated**:

```js
( function() {
angular
  .module( 'app', [] )
  .controller( 'SubmitController', SubmitController );

function SubmitController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.submit = submit;

  function submit( e ) {
    console.log( 'Submit!' );
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
} )();
```

```css
form,
[ng-form] {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ng-submitted {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="SubmitController as vm">
    <div ng-form>
      <form novalidate ng-submit="vm.submit($event)">
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main objective is that submit event was not fired and not arrived to parent element (`[ng-form]`).

Comment: [As I said in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15319#issuecomment-256596025), [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrbgaA) is the CodePen example about it. "Why submit is propagated to parents and not prevented?".

Comment: So you want both the child-form AND the parent form to not be submitted, or just one of them?

Comment: At least, the parent one, stopping propagation.

Comment: Am not clear what you are asking even four people's are answered.

Comment: A mechanism for prevent and stop submit event propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to prevent the form to submit, add this type of logical condition with your **Angular** code:

```
<form name="formName" novalidate ng-submit="formName.$valid && ANY_LOGIC_CONDITION_LIKE_LOGIN.submit()">
```

This will help to prevent the form submission

Comment: I really want to prevent within the called function, not depending on valid state of form. Please, look the added live code.

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATED**

Seeing you code/behavior (after the update)... 

**Why must you submit the child form?** **What is the benefit?** I'm seeing that you are using `novalidate`, so browser validation won't work.
Why you don't simply use a `ng-click="vm.click(myForm)"`. You won't have any troubles with parent form, and angularjs won't add/set any `$submitted` state or `ng-selected` class, so you can handle this manually as you want passing a simple form instance.

<kbd>[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WouFWJw93BpRfjob9yfa?p=preview)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div ng-form>
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm" novalidate >
    <label>My Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="vm.item.myInput" required>
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.click(myForm)">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER/JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    vm.click = function (myForm) {
        alert('submitted');
        //myForm.$valid
        //call to server 
    }
});
```

*If this way fits for your scenario, here you are an awnser... If not, I hope some of others solutions works for you :)*

Comment: I know a similar solution but it is not the searched one. Review the question and look the added live code, please.

Comment: About update: The main goal is stopping propagation of submit event, and this event is only for detecting user submit button confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

See this.
Use `formName.$valid` to prevent submit form and add `ng-model` in your text box.

```js
( function() {
angular.module( 'app', [] )
 .controller( 'FormsController', FormsController );

function FormsController() {
  
 var vm = this;
 vm.submit = submit;
 
 function submit( e ) {
  console.log( 'Submit!' );
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
}
} )();
```

```css
[ng-form],
form {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  &.ng-submitted {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="FormsController as vm">
    <div ng-form>
      <form name="test" novalidate name="test" ng-submit="test.$valid && vm.submit($event)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.test" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [As I said to Kamal Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244766/submitted-form-state-preventing/47941732#comment82849505_47912320), I don't want to depend on valid state.

Comment: And pay attention that CSS code really is Less/Sass and it is used the unnecessary `preventDefault` method, because you used the ancient code. Look the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

See @Taylor Buchanan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233876/unsubmit-a-form-in-angular), once you added the directive. you can simply call it form your JavaScript function.

What you have to do:

1. Add that directive to your code.
2. Add a name to your parent-form: `ng-form="myForm"`.
3. pass your form to your submit function: `vm.submit(myForm)'.
4. And then modify your function:

   function submit( form ) {
      console.log( 'Submit!' );
      form.$setUnsubmitted();
   }

P.S. Since I wasn't sure which one of the forms you wanted to unSubmit, So I assumed you want both. But Obviously, you are getting full controll, so you can modify the code accordingly.

Comment: [The Bear has already proposed this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47917746/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger `$setPristine()` method of FormController. You just need to pass the form itself as an arguement to your submit function and trigger its built in method.

e.g.

**View**:

```
<form name="MyForm" ng-submit="submitForm(MyForm)">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.submitForm = (form) => {
  form.$setPristine();
  alert("Form was submitted")
}
```

[Here's a working example of the above code snippet.](https://jsfiddle.net/fb6szj6d/)

## Update

It doesn't matter if you have nested forms. Propagation doesn't work like you think it does. You should also give your `ng-form` a name. Then pass it down to the submit function and call its built in `$setPristine()` method once more.

Check this code chunk:

View:

```
<div ng-form name="outterForm">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="vm.submit($event,myForm, outterForm)">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function submit( e, form1, form2 ) {
    console.log( 'Submit!' );
    e.stopPropagation();
    form1.$setPristine();
    form2.$setPristine();
  }
```

[Here's an the updated example based on your code chunk demonstrating the nested forms case.](https://jsfiddle.net/x9pr1dfa/)

Comment: It's obvious that, repeating code, it is possible. Logically, this is not a nice solution.

Comment: You're right, but I am afraid there is no other workaround. Propagation doesn't work like that.

Comment: Because of it, my question. Thank you.